# Nesting MySQLI Queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to pull a number from one table inside a database, and then use that number to process a query on another table in the same database.

The code doesn't spit out any errors - it just doesn't return a string! I am trying to understand mysqli and the whole array structure, but I'm having difficulty figuring out why this isn't working. I believe I am trying to successfully turned the original array into a string for use in the second query, which I also translate into a string for the echo. It's just that for some reason it's not printing anything! If I take out the nested loop then it prints the active_event number just fine. I'm at a loss!

```
<?php
$DBServer = 'localhost';
$DBUser   = 'user';
$DBPass   = 'pass';
$DBName   = 'database';
$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$get_active_event = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT active_event FROM asp_config");
while($active_event = @mysql_fetch_assoc($get_active_event)){
$get_event_name = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM asp_events WHERE id = {$active_event['active_event']}"); echo $get_event_name->fetch_object()->event_name;}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Thanks!

-Philip

Comment: what tutorial you are using to learn mysqli?

Comment: I'm not really - largely just going off the PHP manual. I last wrote PHP years ago before MySQLi was very common, so I used MySQL and procedural code. Since I haven't written anything for years switching to the recommended object oriented style is proving a bit of a headache. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to change the logic of your piece of code modifying you db schema in a more efficient way.

I'd fetch the results in a single query joining the two tables asp_config and asp_events or, even better, if possible get rid of asp_config and add a column `is_active`or something like this to asp_events table.

Then you just have to cycle with while-loop without the second query because all you need to know is in the first results set. 
Be careful to use the error suppression (@) you **need** to know if there is an error and handle it. Suppress without knowing it's a bad pratice

Comment: Hm? Error suppression? I didn't believe I was using any. I agree, for a development environment I usually try and have verbose errors on, not suppress them at the code level.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately joining the two tables isn't an option, and I have other queries that need to use the same type of functionality so merging all of the tables into one just isn't doable. That all said, I did figure it out. I think the biggest issue was that I wasn't exiting out of the SQL mode before trying to insert the PHP variable, so I ended up querying a null row which returned a blank dataset. The final code I used is:

```
<?php
$DBServer = 'localhost';
$DBUser   = 'user';
$DBPass   = 'pass';
$DBName   = 'actionsports';
$con = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
if ($con->connect_error) {
trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $con->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$get_active_event = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM asp_config");
while($active_event = mysqli_fetch_array($get_active_event))
{
$get_event_name = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM asp_events WHERE id=('" .$active_event['active_event'] ."')");
if ($get_active_event === false) {
exit("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
while($event_name = mysqli_fetch_array($get_event_name))
  {    echo $event_name['event_name'] ;}}
$con->close();
?>
```

In this case I do have a query loop inside another loop, and it does return the correct data. It might not be the prettiest code, but it works and is what is required for my situation.

Thanks for the help!